# Adding WHERE cause to COUNT query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am having trouble getting a where clause to be part of a COUNT query.

This works to get total count of the table:

```
   $search = $_POST['search_text'];  

    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM
    stories')
    ->fetchColumn();
```

However, when I try to add WHERE stories.category = $search i get syntax errors when I try any of these:

```
$total = $dbh->query('
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        stories
    WHERE
     stories.category = "$search"
');
->fetchColumn();



    FROM
        stories
    WHERE stories.category='$search'


    FROM
        stories
    WHERE (stories.category="$search")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable inside double quotes, but must use concatenation to use one inside single quotes.  (ex..   'my string '.$myvar.' some more string' )

SQL expects strings in either format '' or "" so you can use them interchangeably or with escaped quotes ...

You can escape like this inside of single and double quotes ...

```
"   \"  <--- puts a quote in without terminating the string  "
'   \'  <--- same with single quotes '

$total = $dbh->query("
    SELECT
        COUNT(*)
    FROM
        stories
    WHERE
     stories.category = \"$search\"
")
->fetchColumn();
```

Or

```
 $total = $dbh->query("
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            stories
        WHERE
         stories.category = '$search'
    ")
    ->fetchColumn();
```

OR

```
 $total = $dbh->query("
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            stories
        WHERE
         stories.category = '".$search."'
    ")
    ->fetchColumn();
```

Or

```
$total = $dbh->query('
        SELECT
            COUNT(*)
        FROM
            stories
        WHERE
         stories.category = \''.$search.'\'
    ')
    ->fetchColumn();
```

Also, you can't do this...

```
');
->fetchColumn();
```

You are terminating with semi colon, then trying to invoke an object method.

Comment: If I do "stories.category=$search" I get the error unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR

Comment: None of those 3 solutions work. The first two give the T_OBJECT_OPERATOR error. That last one gives unexpected ‘”‘

Comment: take the semicolon off the paren before ->fetchcolumn();    I will edit answer